# why my code is not turn out the result that I want?

Tags: java, arrays, replace

I want to define a method that input a string then return a string which character in it has been convert

```
public static String encode(String s){
    char[] newArray = {'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','g','k','l','m'};
    char[] newArray2 = {'n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','s','y','z'};

    for(int i=0; i<s.length();i++){

        if(s.charAt(i) == newArray[i]){

            s.replace(newArray[i], newArray2[i]);



        }
    }

    return s;
}

public static void main(String[] args){
System.out.println(encode("firefly"));
```

}

but compiler just return firefly, I know there is a problem in `s.charAt(i) == newArray[i]` but how to define a method , for example, 'f' this single char to search through out the newArray, instead of if f correspond the first char at newArray? also how to define it when I want uppercase letter switch only with uppercase . then if I input a String like FireFly it will return SverSyl?

Comment: Typical ["read the manual"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace-char-char-) question ...

Comment: +1 @Tom even so... I have had this issue bite me before... but I agree... reading the docs should answer the question... or simply debugging and realizing that the string s is not changing....

Comment: Btw: This `newArray[i]` is a bad idea. The size of `newArray` is  always 13, but `s` the be much longer than that, so `newArray[i]` would cause an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` if `i` exceeds `12` (12 is the last accessable index of `newArray`).

Comment: Aside from the obvious issue of not updating s, you also need to scan `newArray` for each character in `s`.  As your code stands, it will only replace characters if they are in a specific index in the string.  Also, for what it's worth, your encoded string will not be decodable because you are only encoding half the alphabet.

Comment: Are you trying to implement Rot13?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, strings in Java are immutable. This mean you can't change them. What you can is create a new one. Second, you compare your string with the translation array to find a match at the same index. It's very difficult to find a match at the same positions and it's not what you want.

You could use the following method:

```
public static String encode(String s) {
    StringBuffer b = new StringBuffer();
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        char c = s.charAt(i);
        if ((c >= 'a' && c <= 'm') || (c >= 'A' && c <= 'M')) {
            b.append((char) ((int) c + 13));
            continue;
        }
        if ((c >= 'n' && c <= 'z') || (c >= 'N' && c <= 'Z')) {
            b.append((char) ((int) c - 13));
            continue;
        }
        b.append(c);
    }
    return b.toString();
}
```

The idea is that you translate each character independently and add it to a string buffer. Then you return the resulting string. To transform a character between 'a' and 'm' you just add 13 to its integer code. To transform a character between 'n' and 'z' you just remove 13 from its integer code.  You do the same thing for the capital letters.

When we call this method with "*FireFly you were cancelled too soon*"

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    System.out.println(encode("FireFly you were cancelled too soon"));
}
```

the result is:

```
SverSyl lbh jrer pnapryyrq gbb fbba
```

Comment: may you explain  b.append((char) ((int) c + 13));  specifically? I do not under stand ((char)((int)c + 13);    also why you add b.append(c) . what is that for?

Comment: its that mean the integer code of char c add 13? but what is integer code? a = 1; b =2; c =3 like this?

Comment: Yes but actually a=97, b=98, ..., z=122

Comment: I mean you have already adjust the char through out the stringbuffer why you still append c in it?

Comment: the stringbuffer is initiailly empty...i take characters from input string, i convert them and append them one by one to this stringbuffer.

Comment: may you explain why you add(char) before(int) c - 13? and yea but why you still add b.append(c); since you have already put converted characters in Stringbuffer. why not just put   return b.toString(); at the end without put b.append(c) in it ? thank you

Answer (score 2):

Because `replace` doesn't change the original `String`.  It returns a new `String`.  You need to write

```
s = s.replace(newArray[i], newArray2[i]);
```

to assign the modified `String` back to the variable `s`.

Answer (score 1):

Strings are immutable. So technically you need to create a new object and assign it a reference. You can assign your previous string itself to it:

s = s.replace(newArray[i], newArray2[i]);

Answer (score 0):

At the end of your code you are returning `s` but it's value has not actually been changed. You need to assign something else to that variable or else you will get the same value you input as the output.